# Appium - switching to a pop up login browser and back

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, appium-android

I use WebdriverIO to test an Android app using JavaScript.

I have a login screen that when I enter an email it pops open a browser to enter the password.

1. How do I switch my driver focus from the app I was in into the login pop up page (default browser of the device)?
2. Could I continue with Appium on that page or should I switch to Selenium because its a web test?